# Como procurar perguntas por temas no Stackoverflow?

Tags: suporte, tags

Estou começando agora  aqui no stackoverflow e fiquei impressionado com a sua performance. Agora para ajudar as pessoas e me ajudar também gostaria de saber se é possível fazer uma pesquisa no site sobre perguntas com um tema especifico? Ou só é possível pesquisar por tags?

Comment: [Como fazer uma busca](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Qual tema você tem em mente? A ideia das tags é representar os temas do site.

Comment: Acho que o que ele quer se resolveria se desse pra refinar a pesquisar para apenas uma única tag. Não existe um operador booleano que pesquise apenas numa tag específica? Tem [até pra achar apenas as respostas duplicadas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), não daria pra ter um (se já não tiver) pra pesquisar apenas dentro de tags específicas?

Comment: Uma dica pra encontrar perguntas sem respostas http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2602/3635

Comment: Obrigado por responder  bfavaretto !! Os temas que tenho em mente são aplicações java , aplicação java web , postgrisSQL ,mysql ,ant!!

Comment: Valeu Guilherme Nascimento vou dar uma olhada!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há várias formas de encontrar assuntos que lhe interessam mais, por exemplo:

1. Ao ver uma tag que lhe interesse, clique nele para ver a lista de perguntas que possuem essa tag.
2. Na página inicial do site, repare que na barra lateral há um item chamado "Tags favoritas" e um link `Editar`. Ali você pode selecionar as tags que deseja acompanhar e o *feed* da página inicial irá destacar as perguntas com essas tags.
3. Quando estiver selecionando as Tags Favoritas no item acima, note que aparece um link `Assinaturas de tags`. Clique nesse link e você vai ser levado a um cadastro para receber atualizações sobre novas perguntas sobre as tags que escolher no seu e-mail.
4. Quando estiver vendo as perguntas de uma tag específica como no primeiro item, role a página até o final e veja que há um link que começa com `Feed de perguntas`. Este *feed* retorna as perguntas de uma tag. Você pode usar um leitor de *feeds* para consumir as atualizações de perguntas naquela tag.

Comment: Muito obrigado utluiz !! Ajudou muito!!